# Can You Prove that a Function Is Holomorphic Without Appealing to Cauchy-Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Suppose that the function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function on some domain $U$. Assume that $U$ is simply connected connected and that the point $z_{0} \in U$. Define a function $g(z)$ as follows: \
\
$$g(z) = \frac{f(z) - f(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}} \ if \ z \neq z_{0}$$
$$g(z) = f’(z_{0})$$

Is it possible to show, WITHOUT assuming the Cauchy Integral Formula, that $g(z)$ is complex differentiable (holomorphic) at $z=z_{0}$. More generally, can it be shown that if a function $F: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is real differentiable, satisfies Cauchy-Riemann-Equations on $U-\{ z_{0} \}$, and if $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_{0}} F(z)$ is finite, then $F$ is real differentiable at $z = z_{0}$ and $F$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann Equations at $z = z_{0}$. My initial thoughts were that we could use the continuity of the partial derivatives to show that the Cauchy-Riemann Equations must be satisfied and $z = z_{0}$. We could also use the fact that $F$ is real differentiable on $U - \{ z_{0} \}$ along with continuity to show that $F$ is also real-differentiable at $z = z_{0}$.

Comment: This depends heavily on what you know about complex differentiable functions. E.g. there is an integration-free proof (due to Whyburn, IIRC) that complex differentiable functions are analytic. If you accept this fact, you may expand $f$ locally about $z_0$ as a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$. Then $g(z)$ is simply $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}(z-z_0)^n$ (with the same radius of convergence as the power series of $f$) and hence it is complex differentiable at $z_0$.

Comment: Where can I find this integration free proof due to Whyburn? Also, what does IIRC stand for and when was this proof created?

Comment: [IIRC](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/iirc), a sketch of proof is given in the appendix of *Complex Analysis* by Alan Beardon. The references he gives include the book *Topology Analysis* by Whyburn and a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-36.1.345) by Read, but now after reading the abstract of Read’s paper, I think Read and Whyburn were probably not the first ones to produce an integration-free proof.

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that $g$ is holomorphic on $U\setminus\{z_0\}$, it suffices to show that $g$ is differentiable at $z_0$.

Choose $r > 0$ so that $\overline{B_r(z_0)} \subseteq U$, where $B_r(z_0)$ is the open disk of radius $r$ centered at $z_0$. Then

$$ g(z)
= \int_{0}^{1} f'(z_0 + t(z-z_0)) \, \mathrm{d}t $$

holds for all $z \in B_r(z_0)$. Moreover, for any $z \in B_r(z_0)\setminus\{z_0\}$,

$$ \frac{g(z) - g(z_0)}{z - z_0}
= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t} f''(z_0 + s(z - z_0)) \, \mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t. \tag{1} $$

Since $f''$ is continuous on the compact set $\overline{B_r(z_0)}$, it is also uniformly continuous on $\overline{B_r(z_0)}$. Hence,

$$ f''(z_0 + s(z - z_0)) \to f''(z_0) $$

as $z \to z_0$ *uniformly* in $0 \leq s \leq t \leq 1$. This allows us to interchange the order of integration and limit, showing

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t} f''(z_0 + s(z - z_0)) \, \mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t
\to \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t} f''(z_0) \, \mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t = \frac{f''(z_0)}{2} $$

as $z \to z_0$. In light of $\text{(1)}$, this proves that $g(z)$ is differentiable at $z = z_0$ with $g'(z_0) = \frac{1}{2}f''(z_0)$. $\square$

Comment: How can it be shown that &f”$ exists and is continuous without invoking Cauchy-Integral Formula?

Comment: I believe this proof would work equally well for real variables under the assumption that $f”$ is continuous.

Comment: In other words, how can it be proven that $f”$ exists and is continuous only under the assumption that $f$ is holomorphic without assuming the Cauchy-Integral Theorem?

Comment: @RobertAbramovic, You are right. I just realized both the existence of continuous and derivative and conservation of holomorphy under locally uniform limit may heavily depend on contour-integral machinery. So, OP's input about what is allowed and what is not would be very crucial.